# Create report dynamically using ParameterFields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have to create crystal report dynamically by using ParameterFields. - In that a single parameter have to call particular row from MySQL database dynamically. Now I called multiple values from MySql database static and single.
I need to call particular row(dynamically) from MySQL database.

```
    Dim sql_Sel As String
    Dim hIssId As Integer = 0
    Dim connectionInfo1 As New ConnectionInfo()
    Dim SqlCon As String = "Data source= *****"
    hIssId = Request.QueryString("patID")
    Try
        CrystLabl.ReportSource = Nothing
        Me.SqlCon.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xyz").ConnectionString
        Me.SqlCon.Open()
        Dim crystalReport As New ReportDocument()
        sql_Sel = "exec DI_Details @opt=1"
        Dim DA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql_Sel, SqlCon)
        Dim DG As New DataSet
        DG.DataSetName = "DataSet.xsd"

        DA.Fill(DG, "DataTable1")
        Dim paramFields3 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterFields()

        For Each i As String In sql_Sel
            Dim paramField31 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField()
            Dim discreteVal1 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue()
            discreteVal1 = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
            paramField31.ParameterFieldName = "My Parameter"
            discreteVal1.Value = ((DG.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) & (DG.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)) & (DG.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3)) >(DG.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6))) 
            paramField31.CurrentValues.Add(discreteVal1)
            paramFields3.Add(paramField31)
        Next

        CrystLabl.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields3
        CrystLabl.ReportSource = "CrystalReport.rpt"
        CrystLabl.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: don't understand you

Comment: frd..i need to create crystal report dynamically.. for that purpose i using ParameterField..

Comment: Right now, im creating the row by giving the row index value. So I'm getting single row corresponding to the index row mentioned in the parameter.
But I need to get the complete data using 'for loop' to achieve my result. So that I can get the complete set of result based on the Stored Procedure value sent by the Parameter.

Comment: why don't you just create generic list of your own class object and just bind it to crystal report this will give all freedom you wanted

Comment: It is client requirement, So that im using parameter instead of binding.